# How to determine which element/resizing value is making my layout overflow it's container

Tags: html, css, css-grid, clamp

I'm learning css-grid by building a page layout and have added some dynamic resizing features to its components so that everything grows and shrinks as the page is resized.

What I've noticed is that when the page is resized to a specific width the contents of my page overflows its bounds, but slightly increasing or decreasing the page width corrects it.

Is there a straightforward way to find out which component or size value is causing this? I suspect it is due to text being resized dynamically using clamp() and vw units and CSS doing something weird when it hits a particular value, but don't want to have to fiddle with every element to work it out.

Here is the full codepen https://codepen.io/kinn81/details/NWYGvzg

Here is the CSS

```
    HTML * {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
    --sb-h1-size: calc(10px + 1.3vw);
    --sb-lg-icon: calc(25px + 1.3vw);
    --sb-h2-size: calc(2px + 1.3vw);
    --sb-sm-icon: calc(12px + 1.3vw);
    --button-width: 6.5vw;
    --button-font-size: clamp(7px, 1vw, 20px);
    --screenWidth: clamp(800px, 98vw, 3000px);

    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: scroll;

}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: var(--screenWidth);
    min-height: calc(var(--screenWidth) * 0.7);
    aspect-ratio: 1/0.7;
    grid-template: 20% 80% / 21% 79%;
}

/* SIDEBAR */
#sidebar {
    grid-row: 1/3;
    background-color: rgb(25 146 211);
    padding-top: 2vw;
}

#sidebar * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*GRID containing 3 rows (heading, navigation, admin)*/
#sb-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 30% 15% 45%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    row-gap: 35px;
}

#sb-heading {
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    font-size: var(--sb-h1-size);
    color: rgb(255 255 255);
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 8px;
}

#headin-icon {
    width: var(--sb-lg-icon);
    height: var(--sb-lg-icon);
}

.align-icon {
    justify-self: center;
}

.item-icon {
    width: var(--sb-sm-icon);
    height: var(--sb-sm-icon);
}

.align-left {
    justify-self: left;
}

#sb-navigation {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    row-gap: 15px;
}

#sb-admin {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    row-gap: 15px;
}

.sb-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 8px;
    font-size: var(--sb-h2-size);
    color: rgb(255 255 255);
}


/* HEADER */
#header {
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    padding-top: 1vw;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#head-top {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

#head-bottom {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

/******HEADER TOP LEFT*********/
#head-top #head-search {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 95fr;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 15%;
}

#head-top>#head-search>div {
    border: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    background-color: rgb(227 232 239);
    border-radius: 50px;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    height: clamp(15px, 2vw, 35px);
}

#head-top #head-search>div>input {
    appearance: none;
    --webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: rgb(227 232 239);
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

#head-top>#head-search>svg {
    width: 8vw;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*****HEADER TOP RIGHT******/
#head-profile {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content;
    column-gap: 1.5vw;
    padding-right: 1.5vw;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#head-profile * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#head-profile>svg {
    width: calc(12px + 1.3vw);
}

#head-profile>img {
    width: 4vw;
    max-width: 90%;
}

#head-profile>p {
    font-size: calc(6px + .8vw);
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*****HEADER BOTTOM LEFT******/
#head-user {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 8.5fr;
}

#head-user {
    display: grid;
}

#head-name {
    display: grid;
}

#head-icon {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: end;
    align-content: center;
}

#head-icon>img {
    width: 8vw;
    max-width: 90%;
}

#head-name :nth-child(1) {
    display: grid;
    align-items: end;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#head-name :nth-child(2) {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: var(--sb-h1-size);
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*****HEADER BOTTOM RIGHT******/
#button-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 1.5vw;
}


#button-container button {
    font-size: var(--button-font-size);

    height: calc(var(--button-width) /2.2);
    width: var(--button-width);

    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(25 146 211);
    color: rgb(255 255 255);
    border: none;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT */
#main-content * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
    background-color: rgb(227 232 239);
    
}

/*MAIN CONTENT LEFT HAND SIDE*/
#mid-container-l {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 12fr;
}

#mid-container-l>p {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 2.4vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: clamp(13px, calc(8px + .8vw), 22px);
}

#inner-container-l {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2vw;
    padding: 0 2vw 2vw 2vw;
}

.project-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 2.5fr 3.5fr 4fr / 1fr 30fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255);
    border-radius: 15px;
    column-gap: 1.5vw;
    height: clamp(120px, 15vw, 15vw);
}

.project-item>h2 {
    font-size: clamp(11px, calc(6px + .8vw), 20px);
    font-weight: 500;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.project-item>p {
    font-size: clamp(8px, calc(1px + 1vw), 15px);
    font-weight: 300;
}

.project-item>:nth-child(1) {
    border: none;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    background-color: rgb(240, 180, 42);
}

.proj-icon-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
    direction: rtl;
    column-gap: 2vw;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.proj-icon-container>div {
    width: 1vw;
}

.proj-icon-container>* {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: calc(4px + 1.3vw);
}

/*MAIN CONTENT RIGHT HAND SIDE*/
#mid-container-r {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    padding-right: 15%;
}

/*MAIN CONTENT RIGHT-UPPER*/
#mid-container-r-upper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 7fr;
    
}

#mid-container-r-upper>p {
    align-self: flex-end;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: clamp(13px, calc(8px + .8vw), 22px);
}

#mid-container-r-upper>div {
    margin-top: 3%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255);
}

.announce-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.5fr;
}

.announce-item:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.announce-item:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.announce-item>h3 {
    align-self: flex-end;
    font-size: clamp(5px, calc(4px + .7vw), 20px);
    font-weight: 500;        
}

.announce-item>p {
    font-size: clamp(4px, calc(4px + .65vw), 20px);
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*MAIN CONTNET RIGHT-LOWER*/
#mid-container-r-lower {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 9fr;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vw;
}

#mid-container-r-lower>p {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: clamp(13px, calc(8px + .8vw), 22px);
}
```

This image illustrates the problem.
[image]

Comment: Try to put a flex-grow: 1 or flex: 1 on the parent container and let me know what it does. :)

Comment: I can try that but have a quick follow up question... Does adding flex-grow require that the container also be set to display:flex? Because I am trying to create this whole thing using only css-grid, no flexbox.

Comment: No, it does not require display: flex; to use flex-grow: 1;

Comment: Sorry that made no difference (but thanks for letting me know flex-grow isn't restricted to flexbox!). If you felt inclined, the codepen is included above if you wanted to take a look.

Comment: Looks good to me...

Comment: What is the specific width that causes the problem?